# reading sms messages from my inbox in j2me

Tags: java-me

how can i read sms messages in my inbox?i want to read the sms msgs ,no of msgs etc
Can i do it in j2me?if yes how?
i want  to run the app on nokia and sony

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4609956/access-to-sms-inbox

Comment: See also http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Discussion/showthread.php?160066-Can-we-access-sms-inbox-in-j2me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can't read sms directly from your inbox.
However you can run your j2me application and wait for incoming sms.
In other words, you can't receive any sms if the application is not running.

Answer (score 2):

unfortunately you will need to wait for midp3 to achieve this unless you are using the blackberry sdk in which case there are classes that enable you to read the message box