# access to sms inbox

Tags: c++, python, java-me, symbian, inbox

How can I access the SMS inbox from an application (on Symbian s60)? Us it possible with j2me? How about C++ or Python?

Comment: See also question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2238764/reading-sms-messages-from-my-inbox-in-j2me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading message from inbox in j2me is **not possible**
if you want to read sms then you can send message using particular port and
your j2me application should listen on that port

otherwise you can go with symbian c++ where it is possible.

Answer (score 2):

In j2me, you can't access the native message box related stuff like Inbox, Sent Message or etc. But it is possible in c++. I don't know about python.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to intercept incoming SMS messages and also view your Inbox, Outbox, Drafts etc with Python for S60. You can find examples of this and many more at [Nokia PyS60 Wiki](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/PyS60). Here's an example of [how to read from your inbox](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/How_read_SMS_in_the_inbox)