# SMS message filter application in Java for Nokia Symbian S60

Tags: java, java-me, mobile, sms, nokia

Want to write a small message filtering application (filter incoming SMSes based on their content to a specific folder) for Nokia E51. Java seems to be the easier route.

Is it possible via Java API for Symbian series 60 phone?
If yes, what exact SDK and tools do I need?

PS: app will be for personal use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible using Java-ME; you can't access the SMS inbox in this way.

However as your target is S60 you have the option of using native Symbian APIs, or Qt (really not too hard).  Check out [this link](http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/CS001617_-_Receiving_an_SMS_in_Qt) for a description of manipulating SMS with Qt.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to read the inbox SMS, unfortunately it's not possible with j2me. But you can possible to read the incoming SMS. Run your application and wait for incoming SMS. Then only it's possible. If your application is not running then it means you can't read the incoming SMS.

For more info see this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2238764/reading-sms-messages-from-my-inbox-in-j2me).

Refer this Nokia forum [discussion](http://discussion.forum.nokia.com/forum/showthread.php?151379-How-to-read-SMS-from-inbox-in-j2me).

And see [this topic](http://www.java-forums.org/cldc-midp/19598-j2me-sms-listener.html) also.

Comment: these articles and the one in my reply below suggest that the normal incoming messages arrive at port 0 and cannot be intercepted (even if my app is running). If I send some messages on a special port (other than 0), then they can be intercepted by listening to that port. Any idea if this is true? I have not done any j2me (or mobile) development and don't have any idea about it.

Comment: see [this existing discussion](http://discussion.forum.nokia.com/forum/showthread.php?205226-Read-SMS&highlight=) on nokia forum.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you have two path to choose.

1. Use some third party library for SMS processing (sending/receiving)
2. Write your own library, which will communicate with device using I/O (most GSM modems can communicate with PC via serial port of some sort - physical or virtual)

For obvious reasons, I recommend choosing the first part. If you look for recommendation, I can strongly recommend using [SMSlib](http://smslib.org/). I've been using it in one of my projects with great success, although some skills were needed to make it all work. After tedious process of installation was over, the rest (sending, receiving, creating callback services) was extremely simple and easy.

If you would like to try the second possible choice, than have a look at [Nokia developers forum](http://www.forum.nokia.com/) and [Java Communications API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-141752.html).

Comment: @Lukasz, correct me if I am wrong, but SMSLib seems to be for use on a PC connected to the mobile via some port. What I am looking for is app on mobile. Also, I don't want to send/recieve some messagegs. Just take some action on incoming messages (i.e. messages landing in SMS Inbox of mobile).

Comment: Right, I guess I got your post wrong, sorry for that. I thought you want to receive an SMS and then process it with your filtering mechanism to transfer it to the PC. So I guess this post relates more to J2ME. Maybe you should change the tags? Hope you'll find an answer.